# SQL query where has children with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have:

- a *parents* table with the following columns: **(id, name)**
- a children *attributes* table with the following columns: **(id, child_id, parent_id, attribute, attribute_value)**

Now I want to filter any **parent id's** that has at least a child with both:

- attribute => `intelligence` of 5
- attribute => `health` of 4

Either one child with `intelligence` of 5 and `health` of 4, or one child has `intelligence` of 5 and another child has `health` of 4.

***How would you query that, in PostgreSQL?*** Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do the intersection of

- parents that have children with intelligence 5
- parents that have children with health 4

```
(SELECT parent_id 
 FROM tab
 WHERE attribute = 'intelligence'
   AND attribute_value = 5       )
INTERSECT
(SELECT parent_id 
 FROM tab
 WHERE attribute = 'health'
   AND attribute_value = 4       )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only wants parents info:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT parents.id, parents.name 
FROM 
  parents 
  LEFT JOIN attributes ON parents.id = attributes.parent_id 
WHERE 
  (attribute = 'intelligence' AND attribute_value = 5)
   OR (attribute = 'health' AND attribute_value = 4)
```

Comment: this does not meet the requirements -- this finds all kids that are one attribute or the other -- not the parents that have kids with both as described.

Comment: Sorry, my bad!, I misunderstood the question, the INTERSECT answer by @lemon looks good!

Answer (score 1):

First we need to join the tables -- like this

```
select p.id as p_id, p.name as parent_name,
       k.* -- we won't need this in later versions
from parent p
join kidatt k on p.id = k.parent_id
```

now we have two attributes we care about -- let make a query that shows those

```
select p.id as p_id, p.name as parent_name,
       case when k.attribute = 'intelligence' and k.attribute_value = 5 then 1 else 0 end as has_a1,
       case when k.attribute = 'health' and k.attribute_value = 4 then 1 else 0 end as has_a2
from parent p
join kidatt k on p.id = k.parent_id
```

we now have a query with a 1 in a row for those that have each of these

now we group by the parent.

```
select p.id as p_id, p.name as parent_name,
       SUM(case when k.attribute = 'intelligence' and k.attribute_value = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as has_a1,
       SUM(case when k.attribute = 'health' and k.attribute_value = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as has_a2
from parent p
join kidatt k on p.id = k.parent_id
group by p.id, p.name
```

now we have a query where a1 and a2 are greater than 0 if one or more child has it.

Now just select the results

```
select * 
from (
  select p.id as p_id, p.name as parent_name,
       SUM(case when k.attribute = 'intelligence' and k.attribute_value = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as has_a1,
       SUM(case when k.attribute = 'health' and k.attribute_value = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as has_a2
  from parent p
  join kidatt k on p.id = k.parent_id
  group by p.id, p.name
)
where has_a1 > 0 and has_a2 > 0
```

*note -- I did not write this query to be the ***best*** way to solve this problem -- instead I wrote it in a way to show you how to "think" in SQL and solve the problem with a series of steps.*

I'd have to test to be sure, but I expect this would be the fastest way to do this query (depends on data and indexes etc.)

```
select distinct p.id as p_id, p.name as parent_name,          
from parent p
join kidatt k on p.id = k.parent_id
where k.attribute = 'intelligence' and k.attribute_value = 5

intersect

select distinct p.id as p_id, p.name as parent_name,          
from parent p
join kidatt k on p.id = k.parent_id
where k.attribute = 'health' and k.attribute_value = 4
```

Comment: Big thanks for your long message, really got me to think. Also about doijng it with an inner join. I would have liked to rate yours as correct but the last solution wiht the `Intersect` just is a bit cleaner. Thank you again. Great work!

Comment: If it got you to think and understand sql better then it was worth it. @JohnSmith